# AddThis on SharePoint Page Layout

Tags: facebook, sharepoint, addthis

I have integrated AddThis share buttons on SharePoint2013 page layout. The problem is when a page doesn't consist an image, what Facebook shares on Facebook page is "spcommon.png" from the 15 hive. /_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png
Is there any way to prevent this from happening, so when a page doesn't have an image, no image gets posted on Facebook page. 
Samples:
Posts spcommon.png
http://www.uhn.ca/corporate/News/Pages/UHN_Accreditation_2011_success.aspx

Posts page image:
http://www.uhn.ca/corporate/News/Pages/ask_expert_h1n1.aspx

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have facing Same problem.
Finally figure Out How to pass our custom Image

try below URL

`http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://enjoymicrosoftsharepoint.blogspot.in/2016/06/how-to-set-item-level-permissions-using.html&picture=http://sharePointsite/PublishingImage/Akshay.jpg`

Please change the property from above URL

**u = SharePoint Page URL**

**picture= image URL from SharePoint site**